# Replicate Matematica code in JavaScript

Tags: plotting

I don't know Mathematica at all, but I'm interesting in replicating some code to reproduce [this animated gif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:QuantumHarmonicOscillatorAnimation.gif).

[image]

Mathematica code is this:

```
(* Source code written in Mathematica 6.0 by Steve Byrnes, Feb. 2011. This source code is public domain. *)
(* Shows classical and quantum trajectory animations for a harmonic potential. Assume m=w=hbar=1. *)
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*** Wavefunctions of the energy eigenstates ***)
psi[n_, x_] := (2^n*n!)^(-1/2)*Pi^(-1/4)*Exp[-x^2/2]*HermiteH[n, x];
energy[n_] := n + 1/2;
psit[n_, x_, t_] := psi[n, x] Exp[-I*energy[n]*t];
(*** A random time-dependent state ***)
SeedRandom[1];
CoefList = Table[Random[]*Exp[2 Pi I Random[]], {n, 0, 4}];
CoefList = CoefList/Norm[CoefList];
Randpsi[x_, t_] := Sum[CoefList[[n + 1]]*psit[n, x, t], {n, 0, 4}];
(*** A coherent state (or "Glauber state") ***)
CoherentState[b_, x_, t_] := Exp[-Abs[b]^2/2] Sum[b^n*(n!)^(-1/2)*psit[n, x, t], {n, 0, 15}];
(*** Make the classical plots...a red ball anchored to the origin by a gray spring. ***)
classical1[t_, max_] := ListPlot[{{max Cos[t], 0}}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[15]]];
zigzag[x_] := Abs[(x + 0.25) - Round[x + 0.25]] - .25;
spring[x_, left_, right_] := (.9 zigzag[3 (x - left)/(right - left)])/(1 + Abs[right - left]);
classical2[t_, max_] := Plot[spring[x, -5, max Cos[t]], {x, -5, max Cos[t]}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thick]];
classical3 = ListPlot[{{-5, 0}}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsolutePointSize[7]]];
classical[t_, max_, label_] := Show[classical2[t, max], classical1[t, max], classical3, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1, 1}}, Ticks -> None, Axes -> {False, True}, PlotLabel -> label, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
(*** Put all the plots together ***)
SetOptions[Plot, {PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Ticks -> None, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Pink]}}];
MakeFrame[t_] := GraphicsGrid[
   {{classical[t + 2, 1.5, "A"], classical[t, 3, "B"]},
    {Plot[{Re[psit[0, x, t]], Im[psit[0, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "C"], 
     Plot[{Re[psit[1, x, t]], Im[psit[1, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "D"]},
    {Plot[{Re[psit[2, x, t]], Im[psit[2, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "E"], 
     Plot[{Re[psit[3, x, t]], Im[psit[3, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "F"]},
    {Plot[{Re[Randpsi[x, t]], Im[Randpsi[x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "G"], 
     Plot[{Re[CoherentState[1, x, t]], Im[CoherentState[1, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "H"]}
    }, Frame -> All, ImageSize -> 300];
output = Table[MakeFrame[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi*96/97, 4 Pi/97}];
SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop"]
Export["test.gif", output]
```

In particular I'm stucked in this line:

```
psit[n_, x_, t_] := psi[n, x] Exp[-I*energy[n]*t];
```

First question:
I first thought to translate it with a multiplication where the *multiplicand* is `psi[n, x]` and the *multiplier* is `Exp[-I*energy[n]*t]`, because I interpret both the space   and the star `*` with the multiplication but.. is it true or does they have a different meaning?

## EDIT

Answer to the first question is (due to comment): space and star have the same meaning, multiplication.

Second question:
with `f(x, t)` as `Im[psit[1, x, t]]` in my JavaScript translation I have those results:

```
x:0,  t: 0,   f(x, t):  0
x:-2, t: 0,   f(x, t):  0
x:2,  t: 0,   f(x, t):  0
x:0,  t: 0.5, f(x, t):  -485738.84954226436
x:-2, t: 0.5, f(x, t):  -4.717559812725077e+136
x:2,  t: 0.5, f(x, t):  3.917168783701828e+49
x:0,  t: 1,   f(x, t):  -710819.418779301
x:-2, t: 1,   f(x, t):  -6.903572006434811e+136
x:2,  t: 1,   f(x, t):  5.732297593069263e+49
```

Can someone plot me results in Mathematica please so I have value to test again?

Just for sake of curiosity this is [my JavaScript code](https://gist.github.com/nkint/0436719e2c6cae01e9cd27009cf5e884)

Comment: both the space and the asterisk are multiplication in that example

Comment: @JasonB. thanks! can you see the edits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, code written for version 6 still works in version 12 (albeit very slowly). Test case:

```
psi[n_, x_] := (2^n*n!)^(-1/2)*Pi^(-1/4)*Exp[-x^2/2]*HermiteH[n, x];
energy[n_] := n + 1/2;
psit[n_, x_, t_] := psi[n, x] Exp[-I*energy[n]*t];
 Flatten[
 Table[{x, t, Im[psit[1, x, t]]}, {x, -2, 2, 2}, {t, 0, 1, .5}], 1]

(*Out[]= {{-2, 0., 0.}, {-2, 0.5, 0.195985}, {-2, 1., 0.2868}, {0, 0.,
   0.}, {0, 0.5, 0.}, {0, 1., 0.}, {2, 0., 0.}, {2, 
  0.5, -0.195985}, {2, 1., -0.2868}}*)

 % // TableForm
```

[image: fig1]

I changed the color and some parameters

```
psi[n_, x_] := (2^n*n!)^(-1/2)*Pi^(-1/4)*Exp[-x^2/2]*HermiteH[n, x];
energy[n_] := n + 1/2;
psit[n_, x_, t_] := psi[n, x] Exp[-I*energy[n]*t];

SeedRandom[1];
CoefList = Table[Random[]*Exp[2 Pi I Random[]], {n, 0, 4}];
CoefList = CoefList/Norm[CoefList];
Randpsi[x_, t_] := Sum[CoefList[[n + 1]]*psit[n, x, t], {n, 0, 4}];

CoherentState[b_, x_, t_] := 
  Exp[-Abs[b]^2/2] Sum[b^n*(n!)^(-1/2)*psit[n, x, t], {n, 0, 5}];

classical1[t_, max_] := 
  ListPlot[{{max Cos[t], 0}}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 1, .5], AbsolutePointSize[15]]];
zigzag[x_] := Abs[(x + 0.25) - Round[x + 0.25]] - .25;
spring[x_, left_, 
   right_] := (.9 zigzag[3 (x - left)/(right - left)])/(1 + 
     Abs[right - left]);
classical2[t_, max_] := 
  Plot[spring[x, -5, max Cos[t]], {x, -5, max Cos[t]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thick]];
classical3 = 
  ListPlot[{{-5, 0}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsolutePointSize[7]]];
classical[t_, max_, label_] := 
  Show[classical2[t, max], classical1[t, max], classical3, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1, 1}}, Ticks -> None, 
   Axes -> {False, True}, PlotLabel -> label, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];

SetOptions[
  Plot, {PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Ticks -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, RGBColor[1, 0, 1, .5]], 
     Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0, 1, 0, .5]]}}];
MakeFrame[t_] := 
  GraphicsGrid[{{classical[t + 2, 1.5, "A"], 
     classical[t, 3, 
      "B"]}, {Plot[{Re[psit[0, x, t]], Im[psit[0, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5},
       PlotLabel -> "C"], 
     Plot[{Re[psit[1, x, t]], Im[psit[1, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
      PlotLabel -> "D"]}, {Plot[{Re[psit[2, x, t]], 
       Im[psit[2, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "E"], 
     Plot[{Re[psit[3, x, t]], Im[psit[3, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
      PlotLabel -> "F"]}, {Plot[{Re[Randpsi[x, t]], 
       Im[Randpsi[x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "G"], 
     Plot[{Re[CoherentState[1, x, t]], 
       Im[CoherentState[1, x, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "H"]}}, 
   Frame -> All, ImageSize -> 300];
output = Table[MakeFrame[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi*96/97, 4 Pi/97}];
SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop"]
Export["test.gif", output, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: @b3m2a1 there was a question about a test case. But, then I added the animation by slightly changing the parameters.